# Micro bibliography inside LaTeX file without filecontents

Tags: bibliographies

How to make nice "micro" (with just a few entires) bibliography inside LaTeX file ?

Requirement:

- not using `filecontents`
- only running `pdflatex file.tex` (might be multiple of times)

I know it's quite limiting (that's why I have problem...), but on the other hand, curious, how to add just a few entries "manually".

I can handle even manually with numbering of references and their layout,
so question could be : how to layout manually to achieve same effect as with BibTex or BibLatex ? But maybe there is some middle ground between doing whole stuff totally manually, and using additional external tools with additional runs.

Comment: You still have the good ol' `\begin{thebibliography}{99}\bibitem.... \end{thebibliography}`

Comment: @percusse: ...`thebibliography`.

Comment: If you go the traditional way with BibTeX, you can then replace the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands with the contents of the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @Werner Ah, of course.

Comment: Thanks you all. Thanks to clues I've found solution immediately, which I've provided for benefit to other tex.SE users.

Answer (score 3):

Solution found in : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28764/7128

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{key01}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}% 2nd arg is the width of the widest label.
\bibitem{key01}
Beeblebrox, Zaphod, Galactic University Press
etc. etc.`
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```